# For continuous invertible $f$, how many discontinuities can $f^{-1}$ admit?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

The inverse of a continuous function need not be continuous. A canonical example is $f:[0,2\pi)\rightarrow S^1$, where $S^1$ is the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $$f(\theta)=(\sin\theta,\cos\theta).$$

We can run with this construction to add more discontinuities to the inverse of a continuous function.

For example, consider a function $g:[0,2\pi)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$, defined by: $$g(\theta)=(\sin\theta,\cos\theta,\sin2\theta,\cos2\theta,...,\sin P_{n}\theta,\cos P_{n}\theta)$$ where $P_{n}$ is the $n$th prime number.

But is it possible to go further still?

This brings me to my question:

> Is it possible to construct a continuous invertible function with its inverse containing uncountably many discontinuities?

My gut tells me no, but I may be wrong, and I have little clue on how to go about proving this. My only thought was to try and decompose $f^{-1}$ into a set of intervals on which the inverse is either CADLAG or CAGLAD. But I am not sure specifically how I could make this construction, or if it is a sensible idea in the first place.

Comment: Please be more specific about any assumptions you may have on $f$.  E.g., is the domain supposed to be an interval, its codomain $\mathbb R^n$, all with the standard topology?

Comment: @JonasMeyer, I can now see why you ask about further assumptions. It was silly of me not to have considered this. But I think Sal's answer is very informative, so I will not edit my question to preclude it. Thank you for your comment, and also your very nice answer. I will leave it some time to give others a chance to answer, but I will accept your answer if nothing else comes along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take

$X=([0,1]\cap\mathbb Q)\cup([-1,0]\setminus \mathbb Q$),

$Y=[0,1]$,

and define $f:X\to Y$ by $f(x) = x^2$.  Then $f$ is continuous and bijective, but the inverse function is discontinuous at every point.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ with its usual topology and let $Y=\mathbb{R}$ with the trivial topology $\{\varnothing,\mathbb{R}\}$.

Then the identity function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous and invertible, but the inverse function
$f^{-1}:Y\to X$ is discontinuous at every point of $Y$.